# How to check if a MDChip is selected in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy-language, kivymd, md-chip

**Python 3.9.0**

### Goal

A way to find if a MDChip is currently selected or not

### Problem

Using the `check` attribute for MDChips to determine if a chip is selected returns **True** even if the chip is selected or not.
I want it to return **false** when the chip isn't selected.

### Example Code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.chip import MDChip

KV = '''
MDRaisedButton:
    id: button
    text: "PRESS ME"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    on_release: app.testing()
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        btn = Builder.load_string(KV)

        self.screen.add_widget(btn)
        return self.screen
    
    def testing(self):
        objects = {0.2 : "Item 1", 0.5 : "Item 2", 0.8 : "Item 3"}
        for pos, item in objects.items():
            chip = MDChip(
                text = item,
                check = True,
                pos_hint = {"center_x":pos, "center_y":0.4},
                on_release = self.fetch
            )
            self.screen.add_widget(chip)

    def fetch(self, chip_instance):
        if chip_instance.check == True:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")


Test().run()
```

> KV script is in the main.py file provided above

### Expectations

[image: I want to select multiple values from the chips and pass them to a function]

[The image is taken from this documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/chip/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution to my own problem. (I am very new to KivyMD, and there might be people with better solutions than I have)

## Solution

```
def fetch(self, chip_instance):
        if chip_instance.color == [0.12941176470588237, 0.5882352941176471, 0.9529411764705882, 1.0]:
            chip_instance.color = [1,0,0,1]
        else:
            chip_instance.color = [0.12941176470588237, 0.5882352941176471, 0.9529411764705882, 1.0]

        if chip_instance.color == [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]:
            print("selected")
        else:
            print("not selected")
```

I am trying to determine which chip is selected based on the color of the chip.
I have made 2 if-else block

### If - Else

**1. Changes the color of the chip**

**2. Determines which chip is selected based on its color**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `check = True`

As shown in above image

You can make a new class and overwrite `on_touch_down` method

```
class SubtitlesChip(MDChip):
    label = 'Subtitles'
    icon = 'closed-caption-outline'
    radius = dp(5)
    check = True

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super(SubtitlesChip, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        is_checked = False
        if self.ids.box_check.children:
            checked = True
        self.do_something(is_checked)

    def do_something(self, checked):
        print(checked)
        # do something else
```

if box_check has no children means its not checked

**This will only work if check is True**